# What can we say about these matrices in terms of eigenvalues/determinants?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are positive symmetric and semidefinite matrices, and $vAv^{\top} < vBv^{\top}$. What can we say about $A$ and $B$ (in terms of eigenvalues/determinants), knowing nothing about $v$?

Comment: $v=e_k$ gives the $k$-th entry on the diagonal. Just knowing this for some $k$ does not say anything about the determinant ot eigenvalues…

Comment: $v$ is some arbitrary vector. Is is true that $det A < det B$?

Comment: Actually, I answered this above… No. Or do you mean to say, that the inequality holds for *all* vectors?

Comment: There exists some $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $v A v^{\top} < v B v^{\top}$ where $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ are positive symmetric and semi-definite matrices.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that $v$ is a specific vector.

All you can say that there is at least one eigenvalue of $B$ that is larger than one eigenvalue of $A$.
In other words, the spectrum of $A$ does not dominate that of $B$.
I don't think you can say anything more.